# Returning/using PreparedStatement from utility class

Tags: java, prepared-statement

I have a piece of code which uses JDBC "Statement" to perform CRUD operations. Now, I need to replace all the Statement with "PreparedStatement" but I am confused about how to return/use it like below code. Please help.

**MyDao.java**

```
    public class MyDao extends BaseDao{

    public MyDao() {
        super();
    }

    public void search(){
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try {
            statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM testTable");
            rs = statement.getResultSet();
            reset();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**BaseDao**

```
  public class BaseDao {

Connection connection=null;
Statement statement = null;

public BaseDao() {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            connection = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("url","user","password");
            statement = connection.createStatement();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void reset(){
        try{
            statement.close();
            connection.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated, you can't. You would have to supply the SQL to be prepared. But the whole design is incorrect. You should not carry around Connections and Statements as instance members of a class. Connections can be closed by the database server any time, especially long-lived ones, at which point you need a new one anyway. Don't give it the chance. You should obtain both as required, and use a connection pool to amortise the costs.

Comment: As you said *You should not carry around Connections and Statements as instance members of a class* , I feel if you can include the reason then it will be helpful for future users. Please share your thoughts

Comment: @EJP: Agreed! but it is a legacy code written years ago and client does not want a huge code change in it. As said I was confused, posted this question to confirm my understanding.Thanks though :-)

Comment: Then you shouldn't change it at all. In any case you certainly can't change it as requested. You can't create a PreparedStatement without the SQL to be prepared.

Answer (score -1):

First check the connection parameters for the database, i assume that you are using a local database so test it with localhost, user, password. If the connection is ok print a console message and then do the CRUD.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question in any way.

Comment: My query is regarding PreparedStatement. Can we use PreparedStatement the way Statement is used in above code?